# Diferença Entre Utilizar "FROM Tabela, Tabela2" X "Join Tabela ON Tabela2"

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Considerando as duas formas de união de tabelas através de um `join`(qualquer um):

```
SELECT Tabela.A, Tabela.B, Tabela2.C 
FROM Tabela
LEFT JOIN Tabela2 ON Tabela.Id = Tabela2.TabelaId
```

E uma união utilizando `from`

```
SELECT Tabela.A, Tabela.B, Tabela2.C 
FROM Tabela, Tabela2
WHERE Tabela.Id = Tabela2.TabelaId
```

Sendo que o dados a serem retornados são os mesmos.

Em uma das querys que rodam na minha aplicação, quando utilizada união através do `from` ao invés de um `join` a diferença de performance é muito alta.

- União com from: 8s
- União com Join: 0.2s

Qual é a diferença entre essas uniões? Quando utilizar uma ao invés da outra?

Comment: Acho que você deve sempre utilizar o JOIN quando você precisa de informações de duas ou mais tabelas que se relacionam, o JOIN deve ser otimizado justamente pra isso.

Comment: Veja [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6442#6442). No seu exemplo, a primeira é um LEFT JOIN a segunda é um CROSS JOIN

Comment: @Pagotti uma união com FROM é equivalente a um Cross Join ?

Comment: @LP.Gonçalves É chamado de [cross join implícito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join)

Comment: @Pagotti não é um `CROSS JOIN`, para isso ele não poderia ter o `WHERE`, devido ao `WHERE Tabela.Id = Tabela2.TabelaId` ele se torna um `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa Os joins tem a ver com a clásula `FROM`. A cláusula `WHERE` tem outra função no `SQL`. O resultado final da consulta é o mesmo, mas a forma como se comporta dentro do otimizador é diferente. Procure por "Álgebra Relacional" para entender melhor essas diferenças. Tem [essa ferramenta online interessante](https://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/calc.htm) que mostra como funciona internamente o SQL.

Comment: @Pagotti por favor consulte a página da wikipédia que você linkou na parte do `INNER JOIN` implicito, você vai ver que por mais que ele seja tecnicamente o mesmo que fazer um `CROSS JOIN`, devido ao filtro pela cláusula `WHERE` o resultado é o mesmo de um `INNER JOIN`, e em bancos de dados modernos o que vai ser feito é um `INNER JOIN`, teste ver o plano de execução do SQL Server por exemplo, pode ser que no passado tivesse diferença, hoje em dia praticamente não tem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao fazer essa consulta, e utilizamos o `LEFT JOIN`, retorna a `tabela` inteira e apenas os registros que coincidirem com a igualdade do `join` na `tabela2` (ou campos nulos para os campos sem correspondência):

```
SELECT Tabela.A, Tabela.B, Tabela2.C 
FROM Tabela
LEFT JOIN Tabela2 ON Tabela.Id = Tabela2.TabelaId
```

> No MySQL, `JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, e `INNER JOIN` são equivalentes sintácticos
>   (que podem substituir-se mutuamente). No SQL padrão, eles **não são
>   equivalentes**. `INNER JOIN` é usado com uma `ON` na cláusula, `CROSS JOIN` é usado de outra forma.
>   <sub>FONTE: [Documentation - Sintaxe JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)</sub>

Ao utilizarmos a ligação das tabelas na clausula `where`, estamos fazendo um simples `JOIN` ou `INNER | CROSS JOIN`, com seu segundo exemplo, ficaria em uma das formas:

```
SELECT Tabela.A, Tabela.B, Tabela2.C 
  FROM Tabela
  JOIN Tabela2 ON Tabela.Id = Tabela2.TabelaId


SELECT Tabela.A, Tabela.B, Tabela2.C 
  FROM Tabela
  INNER JOIN Tabela2 ON Tabela.Id = Tabela2.TabelaId


SELECT Tabela.A, Tabela.B, Tabela2.C 
  FROM Tabela
  CROSS JOIN Tabela2 ON Tabela.Id = Tabela2.TabelaId
```